# svg with absolute positioning and height misbehaves in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

The following HTML file produces something peculiar in Chrome depending if the line `$("#canvas").height(100);` is commented or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 940px;">
            <div><h1>Title</h1></div>
            <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
            <svg id="canvas" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; z-index: -1;">
                <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"/>
            </svg>
            <div id="div1">Hi</div>
            <div id="div2"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function move() {
                var left = $("#div1")[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
                $("#div2").text('left = ' + (left - 5));
                $("#rect").attr("x", left - 5);
                $("#canvas").height(100);
            }

            move();

            $(window).resize(function() {
                move();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When loading the page in a maximized Chrome window then depending on the resolution, the div's text changes to `left = N`. It turns out this value of `N` is off by 7. This can be seen by resizing the window so it's not maximized and then maximizing it again.

This strange behavior doesn't show up when the line `$("#canvas").height(100);` is commented out. You can witness this in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvPCM/1/. You'd have to widen the Result pane to the left until the rect isn't close to the left edge and then hit refresh to see the incorrect drawing. It will be fixed if you resize the pane again. Here how it looks:

Good: [image] Bad: [image]

What can cause this?

FYI: This doesn't show up in Firefox (which ironically required setting the height in the first place).

Comment: Rather than executing that move(); when the script element is loaded try running it in the onload event of the <svg> element.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the way these two browsers renders output.

Chrome renders and runs the scripts as soon as they are ready to run, and it turns out that it does it very fast that the page still is loading some unknown resource (jquery is already loaded there). As I tested it in my browser this leads to having weird scroll-bar (which immediately disappears of course). This scroll-bar changes the page width, that the canvas width is depended on it by the 100% style.
This whole thing causes the bug you've faced it.

FYI: $(document).ready won't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue by setting the height of the canvas at the top, before calling `getBoundingClientRect`.

Still not sure why it reports a different value though.